# Dart, how to change Icon depending on value from firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am trying to change an `Icon` depending on my value from Firebase, but it doesn't work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _activeStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users').where('Active', isEqualTo: 'Yes').snapshots();
```

```
DatatableHeader(
          text: "Active",
          value: "useractive",
          show: true,
          sortable: true,
          sourceBuilder: (value, row){
            return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _activeStream,
            builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Icon(Icons.error);
            }
              return Icon(Icons.check);

            });
          },
```

The `Icon` doesn't change from `Icons.check`.

Comment: Actual data read can be accessed using snapshot.data.

Comment: If all things are equal, the `Icon` doesn't change because the snapshot doesn't get to have data. The if statement is true and that is why the Icons.error is showing. You may want to check snapshot.hasError and check to see if any errors are showing

Comment: Hi, it is not equal. I have two documents in my `Firebase`. One with the value 'No' and the other one with 'Yes'. But it is the same for both documents.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with this:

```
sourceBuilder: (value, row){
            if(value == "No"){
              return Icon(Icons.error);
            }else{
              return Text('');
            }
```